# STD::string as a Member Parameter for Dynamically Allocated Objects

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, std, stdstring

I wish to **dynamically allocate set of objects**(can be several hundreds). Part of those objects are text fields. Because std::string offers nice string manipulations, I would prefer having the object member parameters of type **std:string**.

However, **std::string is dynamically resizable object**. To me, this goes against the dynamically allocated objects containing std::string: There could be allocated memory overflow, if the std::string gets larger than planned.

- Can I kindly ask for advices whether std::string is suitable as a parameter for dynamically allocated objects?
- How to manipulate with std::string, so there will not be memory overflow?
- Is std::string suitable as a member parameter even if hundreds of objects will be allocated dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little difficult to parse, and sample code would have made that easier, I think. Am I right in assuming that you have a class that contains a string, like so:

```
class foo {
  public:
    std::string str;
};
```

and you wonder how the string is resized? Let me try and explain:
The size of objects of class foo is fixed. The size of the string member is also fixed, but it contains in its implementation a pointer to additional dynamic memory (someplace else) that it is growing or shrinking depending on the contents of the string. The implementation of std::string takes care of this for you, you don't need to worry about it. There won't be any memory overflow either - the string's memory is a different block of memory from the block used by the foo-object, for example.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. You understood my question well, and answerred it. I understand the point, and I see, that I do not have to worry about resizing the std::string. I am marking this answer as the *Accptable Answer* and adding +1 as well.